# django summernote is not displaying

Tags: python, html, django

views.py

```
def post_detail(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail')
    else:
        form = PostForm()
        return render(request, 'post_detail.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('Penname','text',)
        widgets = {
            'text': SummernoteInplaceWidget(),
        }
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    #user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    Penname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.Penname
```

post_detail.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  </head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form method="post">
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
  <div>
    <h1>{{  post.Penname    }}</h1>
                                <p>{{   post.text|linebreaksbr  }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
    url(r'^post/$', imagec_views.post_detail, name='post_detail')
]
```

I want a summernote editor option for my text field,but it is displaying only 'Text' string  and summernote is not displaying ,even it is not displaying a simple textfield

Answer (score 2):

Add this in '**settings.py**'

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = "SAMEORIGIN"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you added this lines to your html file?

```
<!-- include summernote css/js-->
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.3/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.3/summernote.js"></script>


$('#text').summernote();
```

Comment: I am included those lines in html , but still in the same state

Comment: also `django_summernote` to INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: I have included that in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Please, look at this url and be sure you have done all required steps

https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote#django-summernote

Answer (score 0):

Check if JavaScript is enabled in your browser.